# How can i use custom function or method in volt

Tags: phalcon

How can i use a function or method in volt?

a function same this:

```
function SumNumber($number1,$numbertwo)
{
  return $number1+$numbertwo;
}
```

or this method on controller

```
public function SumNumber($number1,$numbertwo)
{
  return $number1+$numbertwo;
}
```

how can i register this function or method through controller?

Comment: By calling `$volt->getCompiler()->addFunction('functionAliasForVolt','functionNameInPHP');` See https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/volt.html#id1

Answer (score 0):

As for Phalcon 1.3.x first add the following PHP code. Don't know if engine registration is required, but it worked for me:

```
$di->set('view', function () use ($config) {
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
    $view->setViewsDir($config->application->viewsDir);
    $view->registerEngines(array(
    '.volt' => function ($view, $di) use ($config) {

            $volt = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt($view, $di);
            $options = array(
                'compiledPath' => $config->application->cacheDir,
                'compiledSeparator' => '_'
            );
            $volt->setOptions($options);

            $compiler = $volt->getCompiler();
            $compiler->addFunction('include_raw', function ($resolvedArgs, $exprArgs) use ($view) {
                return sprintf('file_get_contents("%s" . %s)', $view->getViewsDir(), $resolvedArgs);
            });

            [....]

            return $volt;
       }
    ));
    return $view;
});
```

In the template you can call the function this way:

```
{{ include_raw("partials/somePopup.hbs") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I consider a good practice:

A. to create a class **Utility**:

```
/**
* Put here all utility methods you need in views/controllers
*/
class Utility{

    function myCustomMethod($param){
        //Do some stuff here...
    }

    ...
}
```

B. And put an instance of it in your **initialize()** method from **BaseController.php**:

```
abstract class ControllerBase extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Will run when every child controller/action is called, 
     * if method is not overridden       
     */
    public function initialize(){

    //$this->utility can be used in child controller 
    $this->utility = new Utility(); 

    /**
     * To call from view. 
     * Volt eg. {{ utility.myCustomMethod('param_data_here') }} 
     */
    $this->view->utility = $this->utility;

    ...
```